# curved path's and how to make this picture more fancy

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, paths

i want to show that a big frame consist of many small frames of another typ. 
Therefor i started this tikzpicture.

The big one is named `long` and the small frames are named `small`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning, shapes, matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\newcommand{\mylengthlong}{9cm}
\newcommand{\myheightmod}{0.7cm}

\newcommand{\mylengthsmall}{2cm}
\newcommand{\myheightsmall}{0.7cm}
\newcommand{\myfont}{\small}



% vert. distance between small ones and big one
\newcommand{\mydistance}{2cm}

% length of small ones projection on the big ones
\newcommand{\mylengthproject}{0.25cm}


\tikzstyle{long}=[draw, minimum width = \mylengthlong,
minimum height = \myheightmod,
rounded corners]

\tikzstyle{small}=[ minimum width = \mylengthsmall,
minimum height = \myheightsmall,
]

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,  font = {\sf \myfont}]
    % Hilfslinien
%   \draw[help lines] (-7,-7) grid (7,7);

    \node[long] (long) {long};

    \node[small,draw] (small1) at ($(long.north west)+(\mylengthsmall/4,\mydistance)$) {small};
    \draw (small1.south west) .. controls ($(small1.west)+(0,-1)$) and ($(long.west)+(0,1)$) .. (long.west);

    \node[draw, small, right = 0 of small1] (small2) {small}; 
    \draw (small2.south west) .. controls ($(small2.west)+(0,-1)$) and ($(long.west)+(\mylengthproject,1)$) .. ($(long.north west)+(\mylengthproject,0)$);
    \draw (small2.south east) .. controls ($(small2.south east)+(0,-1)$) and ($(long.west)+(2*\mylengthproject,1)$) .. ($(long.north west)+(2*\mylengthproject,0)$);

    \node[draw, small, right = 0 of small2  ] (small3) {small};
    \draw (small3.south east) .. controls ($(small3.south east)+(0,-1)$) and ($(long.west)+(3*\mylengthproject,1)$) .. ($(long.north west)+(3*\mylengthproject,0)$);

    \node[small, right = 0 of small3] (many)    {...};
    \draw (many.south east) .. controls ($(many.south east)+(0,-1)$) and ($(long.east)+(-1*\mylengthproject,1)$) .. ($(long.north east)+(-1*\mylengthproject,0)$);

    \node[draw,small, right = 0 of many] (small4) {small};
    \draw (small4.south east) .. controls ($(small4.south east)+(0,-1)$) and ($(long.east)+(0,1)$) .. (long.east);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Can you think of any better way how to achieve this kind of picture?

Somehow i think this picture doesn't make it clear what i want to show.

Comment: So, do you want to make it fancy OR make it clear first?! Make up your mind. This kind of scenarios, it is good to draw it by hand first (i.e. to make it clear :)).

Comment: I think the waved lines from small part into long part are not good. Why don't you just draw straight line and make vertical line inside long part rectangle to make it CLEAR and just add different colors to make it CLEARER. :))